# placed conf file in sites-avaialable, document file is there in /var/www/html, enabled site, made entry of domain name and ip in /etc/hosts

Tags: apache2, amazon-ec2, aws

I have an aws EC2 instance ubuntu18.04. To host a site i made a conf file in sites-available, placed the document in /var/www/html, has enabled the site with a2ensite and made the host entry in /etc/hosts. ip of my instance in browser is still serving apache default page instead of page i have made. Kindly let me know if this is not the right process.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the default virtual host is overriding the virtual host you created. You can try to disable it using the following commands:

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf
service apache2 reload
```